# AE: Parent Element to a point of a path?

Tags: animation, path, adobe-after-effects

I want to parent an element (pre-compose) to one of the points on a path.

Imagine a line that has two paths. I want to parent an object (say, a leaf) to the top point of the path. So if my path is to have a bounce effect (the point of the path will move to create the effect...), so will my leaf.

Ultimately, it should (the leaf) move the same as my bounce line's top point.

Thanks!

Comment: Benjamin, maybe you could try to reword this. I didn't understand at all. Are you looking to animate object(s) along a path? ...or maybe you want to create sort of like a group, in which to put multiple objects, so that you can easily animate them as one?

Comment: @Joonas Just edited!

Comment: What is this "bounce line"?

Comment: Can you upload a picture with both paths or a simplified After Effects file for us to see what you exactly want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

It's not easy to tell from the question exactly how you have things set up, but it sounds like you're trying to animate an object along a path.

The simplest ways to do this would be to either a) copy the path and use it as the animation path for the object, or b) animate a null object along the path and parent the leaf to that.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to go and download [Chris Green's Script Vertex to Point](http://www.crgreen.com/aescripts/). Then depending on your object you can use that along with Null Objects and Pick Whips to achieve your desired effect.

If your entire line is moving and you want it to track the entire line, not just a vertex then you could do it without the script just by using Null Objects and Pick Whip.

Another way without needing a script, if its a straight line, would be to use Null Objects and Generate Beam. The Beam becomes your line while giving you full usage of X/Y coordinates to Pick Whip to.